# Excel - get everything to the LEFT of character

Tags: excel, formula

I have a cell in excel which looks like this:

```
Paranormal witness (s5)
```

I would like to 1) capitalise the 1st character 2) get everything to the left of the bracket "("

for task 1:

I have this code:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A6933,"'","z-z")),"z-Z","'")
```

for task 2:

I have this code:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1&":")-1)
```

How do I combine the two codes to capitalise and get everything from the left?

expected end output:

```
Paranormal Witness
```

Thanks,
MS

Comment: First character of each word? P and W or just the P?  Perhaps: `=TRIM(PROPER(LEFT(D1,FIND("(",D1)-1)))` assuming value is in D1.  Find the existance of ( and take everything to the left of it -1 character (to exclude the ( itself) and trim to remove leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: It appears that the first character is **already** in caps.

Comment: first character of each word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=TRIM(PROPER(LEFT(D1,FIND("(",D1)-1)))`

I wasn't sure if the ( would be preceded by a space everytime so I used a trim to eliminate extra spaces.

to handle no (

`=TRIM(PROPER(IFERROR(LEFT(D1,FIND("(",D1)-1),D1)))`

This says if an error results from not finding a ( then simply use the name in D1 proper case it and trim off the leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: this works but it returns a "#VALUE!" if D1 has no "(". Would you mind adding a catch? sorry Im new to excel formulas

Comment: Hopefully you don't have any that have two (or more) '('s in them... only text to the left of the first one would make it!

Comment: there are multiple but i'll just have to be careful. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: you could use the text to columns to separate out the ()'s in to separate columns using ( as the deliminator.  then you don't have to do the find or left at all... or use a replace to change them all to ~ or something and then use text to columns on it...  Just depends on what your end game is.  (date Text to columns) nice feature for parsing out data!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=PROPER(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1)-2))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on David Zemens' comment, this should be used:

```
=PROPER(LEFT(A1,FIND("(",A1 & "(")-1))
```

It will also handle cases in which the open parenthesis is missing.

Comment: use `-1` unless it's safe to assume that whitespace always precedes the parens?

Comment: @DavidZemens  the formula is designed with the example in mind, but I agree that ***-1*** would be better.

Comment: " get everything from the left?" would imply that OP wants to preserve whitespace. Now, that may not actually be the intention (but it's not clear either way), in which case `Trim` function is probably yet more appropriate. +1 either way. :)